# How to automatically generate new UUID in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, uuid, dbeaver

I'm using PostgreSQL version 14.4.  I installed the `uuid-ossp` extension.

I created a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE reserved_words 
  ADD id uuid NOT NULL DEFAULT uuid_generate_v1()
  ADD word NOT NULL varchar(20);
```

Unfortunately, when I try adding a new record, rather than a new UUID being generated, instead the "uuid_generate_v1()" string is added in as the `id`!

I've scoured the Internet but can't find out how to alter things so that the function itself is executed.  Any ideas?

Comment: Since Postgres 13 you can use the built-in function `gen_random_uuid` no need to install an extension

Comment: For versions other than v4 (random), the uuid-ossp extension must be installed.

Comment: uuid v1 is essentially mac address + a timestamp.  uuid v4 is a cryptographically secure hash that is guaranteed unique for a few centuries, with the odds of a collision being somewhat less than the odds of randomly picking an individual electron out of tevery electron in hte entire universe.

Answer (score 3):

My apologies, it actually does work.  What's happening is that in DBeaver, the DB client I user, it does at first show the UUID generation function but then when you save the new record, it creates the UUID correctly.

Note: I don't really understand the difference between `uuid_generate_v1` and `uuid_generate_v4` but am going to opt to use the latter one.

Answer (score 3):

The foremost point is that data type should be of `uuid`

The 'uuid-ossp' extension offers functions to generate UUID values.

To add the extension to the database run the following command

`CREATE EXTENSION "uuid-ossp";`

you can use the core function gen_random_uuid() to generate version-4 UUIDs.

To make use of this function in dbeaver ,follow the steps:

1.Go to table in which you want to generate UUID's

2.In the table properties tab find the column to which you need to apply the
uuid function

3.Double click on the column name and it will show expanded view of it's
properties

4.Under *default* value of that particular column properties, write the
function name as shown in the image
**gen_random_uuid()**

[Dbeaver illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oqC97.png)

Comment: gen_random_uuid() works in pgAdmin as well, no need for extensions

Answer (score 2):

`uuid_generate_v1 () → uuid`

Generates a version 1 UUID. This involves the MAC address of the computer and a time stamp. Note that UUIDs of this kind reveal the identity of the computer that created the identifier and the time at which it did so, which might make it unsuitable for certain security-sensitive applications.

`uuid_generate_v4 () → uuid`

Generates a version 4 UUID, which is derived entirely from random numbers.

[source](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/uuid-ossp.html)